# How come I can't edit the partitions of this USB drive?

Tags: ubuntu, disk, gparted

I'm trying to divide a USB thumb-drive into multiple partitions using gparted, but for some reason the *Delete* option is greyed out. How come?

The drive is unmounted, but the only available option is to resize (which fails). The screenshot didn't want to include drop-down menus for some reason.

I guess I can get around it using fdisk, but now I'm curious to why gparted is behaving like this.

I did start it as root.

[image: GParted won't let me delete]

I eventually got it working by creating a new partition table. That is, until it failed on actually creating the new table:

[image]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a partition table on the device, the entire `sda` drive is formatted to NTFS. If you want to create multiple partitions on it, you first need to create a partition table with *Device -> Create Partition Table* (note this will destroy the existing NTFS filesystem so if you have some data on it you need to make a backup first) and then add new partition(s) using *Partition -> New*.

Comment: Aha, it would let me create a partition table, thanks!

Comment: The error looks like the drive disappeared when GParted tried to create the partition. Check journal or dmesg if there are some errors about `sda`, the flash drive might be dying (or the USB connector is loose or dirty).

Comment: I think you are right. The drive keeps popping in and out, so I'm going to get a new drive before I continue. Thanks!